# How to conventionally map controller actions to routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have rails 5.1 application and have some set of routes under `controller do` block.

```
controller "pages" do 
    get "/dashboard", action: "dashboard"
    get "/guide", action: "guide"
    get '/welcome/:email', action: "welcome"
    get '/guest/:email', action: 'guest'
    get '/settings', action: "settings"
end
```

As you can see all routes name are actually mapping to same named action. I am looking for any possibility to DRY it up. Something similar to this.

```
controller "pages" do 
    get "/dashboard"
    get "/guide"
    get '/welcome/:email'
    get '/guest/:email'
    get '/settings'
end
```

Please consider that I want the routes as `/dashboard` and not `/pages/dashboard` which is the reason of not using the conventional routes i.e `get /pages/dashboard` generated by scaffold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like so:

```
controller "pages" do 
    get :dashboard
end
```

this will route /dashboard to `Pages#dashboard` which you can verify with `bundle exec rake routes | grep dashboard`

Comment: and how do we add params in this?

Comment: i'm not sure you can